Asymptotic roots of equation involving Bessel functions
Let $r_2>r_1>0$, $g\ge 0$, and let $\lambda_n$, $n=1,2,\ldots,\infty$, be the positive roots of
\begin{equation}
J_g(xr_2)Y_g'(xr_1)-J_g'(xr_1)Y_g(xr_2)=0,
\end{equation}
where $J_g'(xr_1)$ is the derivative of $J_g(xr)$ with respect to $r$ evaluated at $r=r_1$, and similarly for $Y_g'(xr_1)$.
The asymptotic roots as given in the handbook of Abramowitz and Stegun are
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_n\sim \frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2(r_2-r_1)}+\frac{r_1(1-4g^2)+r_2(4g^2+3)}{4(2n-1)\pi r_1r_2}.
\end{equation*}
The question is: How does one derive the above asymptotic root expression using Mathematica?
I am aware that the Asymptotic function in Mathematica gives the behavior as $x\rightarrow\infty$ of $J_g(xr_2)Y_g'(xr_1)-J_g'(xr_1)Y_g(xr_2)$
in terms of $\cos[(r_2-r_1)x]$ and $\sin[(r_2-r_1)x]$ as
\begin{equation*}
\frac{8r_1r_2x\cos[(r_2-r_1)x]+\left[r_1(1-4g^2)+r_2(4g^2+3)\right]\sin[(r_2-r_1)x]}{8r_1r_2x}.
\end{equation*}
Using this expression or otherwise, how does one finally get the asymptotic root expression.

You can use McMahon’s method to "invert" that asymptotics for the roots. See, for instance, Watson pp. 503–507.

@Gary Thanks a lot for providing the reference. I manged to get McMahon's 1894 paper also which derives the asymptotic root formulae. The method is however quite involved. and there appears to be no easy method even with the use of symbolic computation software.

Perhaps you can take a look at this paper on the analogous problem for the Airy zeros: https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=150751 A method for the computation of the coefficients in the McMahon expansion is discussed here: https://doi.org/10.1137/21M1396794

I looked at both the papers. Both of them talk of the `reversion' of the asymptotic form which is nevertheless quite complicated. Their goal is to get the successive terms by means of a recursion process. My goal is just to get the first two terms since I have found that two terms is quite sufficient for a Newton-Raphson to work. The danger which one should be aware of (in many although not all cases) is that one can miss out on the lowest roots since there is no asymptotic root near to those roots. Adding more and more terms to the asymptotic expansion does not help to identify these roots!

With the notation of $\S10.18$ in the DLMF, we can write
$$
J_g (xr_2 )Y'_g (xr_1 ) - J'_g (xr_1 )Y_g (xr_2 ) =- M_g (xr_2 )N_g (xr_1 )\sin (\theta _g (xr_2 )-\phi _g (xr_1 )).
$$
By $\S10.18(\text{iii})$, we have
$$
\theta _g (xr_2 )-\phi _g (xr_1 ) = x(r_2  - r_1 ) - \frac{\pi }{2} + \frac{{ r_1 (4g^2  - 1)-r_2 (4g^2  + 3)}}{{8r_1 r_2 }}\frac{1}{x} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^3 }}} \right)
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. The $n^{\text{th}}$ root $\lambda_n$ satisfies $\theta _g (\lambda _n r_2 ) -\phi _g (\lambda _n r_1 ) = \pi (n-1)$ with $n\ge 1$. Applying asymptotic inversion for
$$
\pi (n-1) = \lambda _n (r_2  - r_1 ) - \frac{\pi }{2} + \frac{{ r_1 (4g^2  - 1)-r_2 (4g^2  + 3)}}{{8r_1 r_2 }}\frac{1}{{\lambda _n }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\lambda _n^3 }}} \right),
$$
gives
$$
\lambda _n  = \frac{{(2n - 1)\pi }}{{2(r_2  - r_1 )}} - \frac{{r_1 (4g^2  - 1) - r_2 (4g^2  + 3)}}{{4r_1 r_2 (2n - 1)\pi }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right).
$$
(Remark: $y = x + \frac{a}{x} + \mathcal{O}\big( {\frac{1}{{x^3 }}} \big) \Longleftrightarrow x = y - \frac{a}{y} + \mathcal{O}\big( {\frac{1}{{y^3 }}} \big)$.)
See $\S10.21(\text{x})$ in the DLMF for further terms and information.
